# FLEX Android: Do I need to copy .db and .xml to ApplicationStorage manually?

Tags: android, file-io, flex4.6

On flex app for Android first start (or after deleting app data), does Flex handle copying assets files from assets/ folder to File.applicationStorageDirectory, or is developer responsible for checking whether file exists there, and if not, copying ones from assets/ to File.applicationStorageDirectory?

If this goes by unanswered, I don't mind investigating it further and answering it myself, I was just wondering if someone knows this by heart.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you use Flash Builder?

In its menu there is Project -> Export Release Build... -> Next -> Package Contents and you can add your assets by toggling checkboxes.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. Question was - does the asset gets copied to ApplicationStorageDirectory (since it is considered a good practice to keep one's files there) automatically on first launch, or do we have to do that.
In the meantime I investigated it, and posted an answer to my own question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here goes:
Flex **does not** take care of that - we have to do it manually.
I will use the following code to make sure my file exists in ApplicationStorageDirectory:

```
import flash.filesystem.File;
public const FNAME:String = "myDBFileName.db";

private var dbFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(FNAME);

// 'original', initial file
private var originalDB:File =File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(FNAME);      

public function MyOpenFile(){

if (!dbFile.exists){ 
    // It does not exist in AppStorageDirectory, so copy it from app instalation directory
    originalDB.copyTo(dbFile);
}
    // from here on, we can safely use dbFile.
}
```

So on 1st launch (and after 'delete app data'), app will copy original file to ApplicationStorageDirectory, and continue using it from there.